# How can I cluster a list of lists in Python based on string indices? Need insight

Tags: python, regex, string, list, python-2.7

I have a list of lists in this fashion.

```
[['Introduction', '0 11 0 1 0'],
['Floating', '0 11 33 1 0'],
['point', '0 11 33 1 1'],
['numbers', '0 11 33 1 2'],
['IEEE', '0 11 58 1 0'],
['Standard', '0 11 58 1 1'], 
['754', '0 11 58 1 2']]
```

I want to cluster/group the words in the list based on its string indices. The grouping is based on the first 3 numbers of the string index. What would be the best way to tackle this problem. I am thinking of using regular expressions. Is there a direct and easy way to this grouping?

**Expected Output:**

```
Introduction 0 11 0
Floating point numbers 0 11 33
IEEE Standard 754  0 11 58
```

Comment: Why is your expected output cutting some numbers off of the second element?

Comment: I'm going to throw out the obligatory "what have you tried so far?" Do you have any code you can show us? I'd much rather help you by fixing faulty code than writing you a solution from scratch.

Comment: @enginefree No, group words based on first 3 numbers considering the next set of numbers to find order of word in reconstructed phrase. Basically I am trying to reconstruct phrases(section headings) using the number indices.

Comment: For each entry in the list, split the second index on `(space)`, chop it to contain first three elements `[:3]`, use that as the key in a dictionary. For each key add the first index of original entry to the value list.
Code this into Python and you should be done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe using `itertools.groupby`?

```
from itertools import groupby
def key(item):
    return [int(x) for x in item[1].split()[:3]]

master_lst = [['Introduction', '0 11 0 1 0'],
              ['Floating', '0 11 33 1 0'],
              ['point', '0 11 33 1 1'],
              ['numbers', '0 11 33 1 2'],
              ['IEEE', '0 11 58 1 0'],
              ['Standard', '0 11 58 1 1'], 
              ['754', '0 11 58 1 2']]

for k,v in groupby(master_lst,key=key):
    print ' '.join(x[0] for x in v) +' ' + ' '.join(str(x) for x in k)
```

Results in:

```
Introduction 0 11 0
Floating point numbers 0 11 33
IEEE Standard 754 0 11 58
```

Comment: I've wondered sometimes if StackOverflow needs a tool where if you're interested in working on a problem you can click on it and give a few words on your approach ("groupby") or something, to avoid duplication of effort.  Unfortunately newbies might refrain from writing up a perfectly good answer if they see a five-digit karma type is working on it -- I know I probably would have, back in the day -- so I'm not advocating it, but still. :^)

Comment: I've seen people weigh in with a sentence and then edit to expand. The fastest Pythonista on SO does this, and his answers are of notably high quality once completed.

Comment: @mgilson Awesome!! that worked perfectly. I was messing up this idea using dictionaries and nested loops. Just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! I am learning a lot from you guys.

Comment: @DSM -- Yeah, that would be kind of nice.  I was amazed at how similar our answers were ... And I had it sitting here working on it for a while before I decided it was sufficiently complex that I probably ought to test it before posting ...